# Is there a selector to exclude display: none elements?

Tags: html, css, display

I want to select only `<buttons>` whose parents have `display: block` and exclude those `<buttons>` whose parents have `display:none`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: If the `display: block` and the `display: none` parents are different classes, then you can select the buttons based on that.

Comment: Why do you want that? If an elements parent is `display: none` then it simply won't render. It doesn't matter what other properties are applied to it.

Comment: If those `display` styles are declared inline then you can use the following selectors: `div[style*="display: none;"]` *(if element has inline style attribute containing "`display: none;`" then apply style)*

Comment: try using is(":visible") with jquery.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Hey, your solution works. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Happy to @alex - just need a few minutes...

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError that will work with inline styles only.

Comment: @Amit yes, you're right, but I did mention that: *"If those display styles are declared inline..."*

Comment: Answer added, alex.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If those `display` styles are declared *inline* then you can use the following selectors: `div[style*="display: none;"]` *(if element has inline style attribute containing "display: none;" then apply style)*

**Attribute Selectors:**

> The CSS **attribute selector** matches elements based on the presence
>   or value of a given attribute.

*Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors*

**Attribute Contains Selector:**

> When looking to find an element based on part of an attribute value,
>   but not an exact match, the asterisk character, *, may be used within
>   the square brackets of a selector. The asterisk should fall just after
>   the attribute name, directly before the equals sign. Doing so denotes
>   that the value to follow only needs to appear, or be contained, within
>   the attribute value.

*Src: https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/*

Answer (score 42):

Actually there's a CSS3 solution to select elements that doesn't have a `display:none` style, or given an explicit `style` property:

```
*:not([style*="display: none"]) button{ ... }
```

**Demo:**

```css
*:not([style*="display: none"]) button{
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<p style="display:block">
  My name is A.
  <button>
a
</button>
</p>
<p style="display: none">
  <button>
b
</button>
</p>
```

Comment: It may be a solution, but not at all a good recommendation on standard as you are using inline styling.

Comment: Well maybe it's a limitation of using inline style, but it's a solution, otherwise we will be using JavaScript or jQuery for it.

Comment: @invinciblemuffi glad it helps you :)

Comment: And "space" matters

Answer (score 3):

No.

There are no selectors which select elements based on the values of properties that apply to them.

---

I don't think it would be practical for CSS to introduce such a feature either. Imagine:

```
:has-property-value(display: none) {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with pure `CSS` so far, 
Unless you explicitly specify the inline css to `style="display: none"`.

You could use some javascript to filter a set of `buttons` that are visible.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.block button');

var visibleButtons = [];

buttons.forEach(function (element) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(element.parentNode).display !== 'none') {
   visibleButtons.push(element);
  }
});

console.log(visibleButtons);
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button>btn 1</button>
</div>

<div class="block hidden">
  <button>btn 2</button>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <button>btn 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually [**it's possible with CSS3**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787219/3669624) to select elements using a style property.

Comment: @cнŝdk Not really since the solution you link to requires inline styling. The poster, however, offers a universal solution as it works with computed style regardless with it is declared inline or in a head CSS element.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such selector available in CSS to select by their property values. You can try something with jquery by using `:hidden` selector to find buttons with `display:none`. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$( ".btnShow" ).click(function() {
  $( ".btn:hidden" ).show( "fast" );
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.btnShow{
  display:block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="button 1" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="button 2" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="button 3" class="btn hidden">
<input type="button" value="button 4" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="button 5" class="btn hidden">
<input type="button" value="button 6" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="button 7" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="Show hidden buttons" class="btnShow">
```

Comment: Actually [**it's possible with CSS3**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787219/3669624) to select elements using a style property.

Comment: As per my knowledge no one approach for inline style.

Comment: @chsdk — That selects elements based only on the value of a style attribute, not on the computed CSS property.

Answer (score -4):

You can check with jquery. The code below means

> "Get all buttons, filtered by ones whose parent is visible on page", 
>   loop through and print html of each one.
>
> ```js
> $(document).ready(function(){
> $(":button").filter(function() { return $(this).parent().is(':visible') 
>        }).each(function(){
>         console.log($(this).html());
>   });
> });
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <p class="intro" style="display:block">
>     My name is someone.    
>    <button>    a    </button>    <button>    b    </button>    
> </p>
> <p>I live somewhere.</p>    <p>My best friend is someone.</p>
> Who is your favourite:    
> <ul id="find" style="display:none">
>   <li>One</li>      <li>Two</li>      <li><button>    x    </button>    
>   <button>    y    </button></li>    
> </ul>
> ```