# Adjacent sibling matches elements with display: none

Tags: html, css

I have quite a simple bit of CSS formatting - or so I thought!

I have two adjacent elements, the first of which can be hidden. I've used display: none to hide it.

The second element is always present.

I need to maintain a space between the two, so I thought the following bit of CSS would be sufficient:

```
.hidden + .visible {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

However, it seems that although the first element has display: none applied, the selector is still matches the second element as adjacent (not first), so applies the margin.

Aside from finding it quite 'odd', I need to find a way of keeping a space between the two, but only when both are visible.

Any ideas?

There's a snippet attached with an example.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  background-color: lime;
}
.hidden + .visible {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item hidden">hidden</div>
    <div class="item visible">visible</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use attribute selector but style tag is only work if you have inline CSS

Comment: Thanks for that - I learnt something new.

Comment: @JohnOhara try my solution to use selector `:not(.hidden) + .visible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change `.hidden + .visible` to `:not(.hidden) + .visible`**

CSS will continue to apply that class format, regardless of it's display: setting, because the element still exists. And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786663/is-there-a-selector-to-exclude-display-none-elements) I believe there isn't any way for a plain CSS selector to tell something's display is :none unless it is inline.

So let's **use their class name in `:not(.hidden)`**. See below.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  background-color: lime;
}
:not(.hidden) + .visible {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item hidden">hidden</div>
    <div class="item visible">visible</div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Show/Hide" onclick="var cn=document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0].className;
  document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0].className=(cn=='item visible'?'item hidden':'item visible');">
```